# toggleclass with missing background-image

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an ID that I want to toggle to show additional info when clicked. However, when I run JavaScript, the images go missing.

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
});
```

```css
.show-description p {
  height: 150px;
}

.show-description small {
  opacity: 1;
}

.first {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1000");
}

.price {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <p>pumpkinnie
    <small>awesome air fried pumpkin strips. </small></p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code here wouldn't do what you describe. Please look at the snippet demo I created from your code and revise it to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use "background-size" property and set as 'contain' or 'cover' the image will not disappear since your code is correct. it may be not enough size.

make sure your image file is loaded correctly or check with this online image url: https://i.picsum.photos/id/16/200/300.jpg?hmac=k64O1qCMBhaU0Ep_qML5_xDxqLVR1MhNm8VMqgdAsxA

```
background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/16/200/300.jpg?hmac=k64O1qCMBhaU0Ep_qML5_xDxqLVR1MhNm8VMqgdAsxA');
background-size: contain;  //or
background-size: cover;
```